# Align text and logo

Tags: horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to find a way to place a logo at the top left of the page, with **at the same height** and right aligned my information (eg name, adress). The rest of the text has to be placed below that.

I can't find how to do that. My problems are

1. my information (name) is not on the same height as the logo;
2. the text just starts under my name, on the right side of the logo, not under it.

Most search results I saw are about headers and footers and I'm not looking for that.

My code:

```
\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0.5\textwidth}
  \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{D:/SkyDrive/Backup/Latex/logo.jpg} 
  \end{center}
\end{wrapfigure}

\begin{flushright}
    \noindent name\\
    info\\
    \today
\end{flushright}

Text
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It is considered a lot better to put in some code that will compile, as it makes it a lot easier for us to copy it into our text editor and work with it, and see exactly what it is you are trying to do.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.

Comment: OK, added my code.

Comment: Some additional options can be found [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69507/how-can-i-align-some-text-with-a-logo)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems like a crude way of doing it, but it is fairly straight forward:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,graphicx,lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{array,graphicx,lipsum}
\begin{document}
\noindent\begin{tabular}{@{}p{.5\textwidth}@{}>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{.5\textwidth}@{}}
   & My name \\ & My street \\ & My city \\ & My postal code \\ 
  \smash{\includegraphics[height=5\normalbaselineskip]{example-image-a}} & My country
\end{tabular}

\lipsum
\end{document}
```

I've made the height of the image be equivalent to the height of the name/address portion (5 lines or `\normalbaselineskip`s). Inserting the image on the same line as the last entry of your address allows you to use `\smash` to avoid any vertical adjustment within the `tabular`.

Some components involved in the solution:

- `\noindent`: Removed the regular paragraph indent inserted when starting a paragraph (note that this happens with the first *Lorem ipsum* paragraph below the image);
- `@{}` in the `tabular` column specification removes the inter-column spacing inserted usually between adjacent columns like. This space inside a `tabular` is given by `\tabcolsep`;
- `>{<stuff>}`: This is a directive offered by the [`array` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/array) that inserts `<stuff>` *before* the start of the cell. An analogous `<{<stuff>}` is also provided (but not used) for inserting `<stuff>` *after* the end of the cell. I insert `\raggedleft` to make the cell contents be flush with the right margin. There's also `\arraybackslash` which is a correction tool when using the `>` and `<` directives, re-establishing the functionality of `\\`;
- `p{.5\textwidth}`: Both columns in the `tabular` are set in `p`aragraph mode/style with a width of `.5\textwidth` - half the text block width.
- `\smash`: removes any vertical height of an object which would otherwise influence the line gap between successive rows in the `tabular`.
- `\normalbaselineskip`: The regular `\baselineskip` that is used outside the `tabular` environment is captured in `\normalbaselineskip` for use inside the `tabular`, if needed.
  I made the image as high as 5 lines, since my personal details spanned 5 lines.

Comment: Thanks works perfectly! Don't fully understand how it workes though :p

Comment: @Aaron: I've added some detail.